# Fast way of copying multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have multidimensional array of Struct in C++.

```
#define TOTALSTREAMS 5
#define SEQUENCEHISTORY 20
#define PROCESSINGSIZE 5
#define OVERLAPPINGSIZE 1
#define X_GRID   100//X_GRID and Y_GRID represents the whole building in CM
#define Y_GRID   70
typedef struct {
   uint64_t localid;
   uint64_t globalid;
   int  posture;  
   std::vector<float> feature;
} person;
typedef struct {   
   std::vector<person> people;
} griddata;

griddata History_host[SEQUENCEHISTORY][TOTALSTREAMS][Y_GRID][X_GRID];
griddata Processed_Array[PROCESSINGSIZE][TOTALSTREAMS][Y_GRID][X_GRID];
```

Need to copy from one array to another. What I did was just copy in simple way as follows. It is slow. How can I copy such array in faster way?

```
          for(int i=0; i<PROCESSINGSIZE; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<TOTALSTREAMS; j++){
                for(int k=0; k<Y_GRID; k++){
                   for(int m=0; m<X_GRID; m++){
                      for(int n=0; n<History_host[i][j][k][m].people.size(); n++){
                         Processed_Array[i][j][k][m].people.push_back(History_host[i][j][k][m].people.back());
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
```

Comment: With `std::array`, it would require less lines.

Comment: In C++ you don't need that C struct declaration, you could directly `struct griddata{...}`

Comment: successive `push_back` can be omitted BTW.

Comment: your inner loop could just be `Processed_Array[i][j][k][m].people.assign(History_host[i][j][k][m].people.begin(), History_host[i][j][k][m].people.end());`

Comment: Best solution is write code in such way that coping is not needed. But you didn't explain what this code does or what are properties of this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted does not copy the arrays content properly.
The assignment

```
Processed_Array[i][j][k][m].people.push_back(History_host[i][j][k][m].people.back());
```

will not copy the arrays content, but only add the last element of the source array several times. You should use the index n to access the appropriate element.

Here are some hints to increase the copy speed:

- use std::vector<>.reserve() to allocate the vectors elemets before using std::vector<>.push_back(). Vectors will grow dynamicaly of no initial Size is given, this is a costly operation.
- Try to avoid the usage of std::vector<> and use fixed size arrays (if possible). Fixed size arrays can easily copied with memcpy()

Comment: No way I know in advance for the size of people for each grid.

Comment: Can you set an upper limit for the array size ?

Answer (score 0):

Biggest problem I see it that this code is to much `C`-like.

- use of macros for constant
- use of explicit C-array
- `typedef` which is a good practice in `C` and obsolete in `C++`.

To make this more like C++ code:

```cpp
constexpr size_t TOTALSTREAMS = 5;
constexpr size_t SEQUENCEHISTORY = 20;
constexpr size_t PROCESSINGSIZE = 5;
constexpr size_t OVERLAPPINGSIZE = 1;
constexpr size_t X_GRID = 100; //X_GRID and Y_GRID represents the whole building in CM
constexpr size_t Y_GRID = 70;

struct person{
   uint64_t localid;
   uint64_t globalid;
   int  posture;  
   std::vector<float> feature;
};

struct griddata{   
   std::vector<person> people;
};

using griddata_streams = std::array<std::array<std::array<griddata, X_GRID>, Y_GRID>, PROCESSINGSIZE>;

using history_host = std::array<griddata_streams, SEQUENCEHISTORY>;
using processed_array = std::array<griddata_streams, PROCESSINGSIZE>;

history_host History_host;
processed_array Processed_Array;
```

Now simple assignment does the job and other parts of code remains unchanged.

Now about performance. To improve there are only tree choices:

- above code - there is problem with `push_back` it can reallocate vector buffer multiple times as vector grows. Use of `std::vector::reserve` can prevent this.
- use COW - Copy On Write technique (it can be done without extra context of your problem)
- analyze problem which this code should solve and look there for possible optimizations. For this we just have to know what your code does and what are properties of your input data. For example there is something called sparse matrix which could greatly improve performance.

Note also that your original code has UB: buffer overflow, since `SEQUENCEHISTORY > PROCESSINGSIZE`.

To copy this you can do this:

```cpp
std::copy_n(History_host.begin(), std::min(History_host.size(), Processed_Array.size()),
            Processed_Array.begin());
```

Comment: just assigning each `griddata_streams` should work,isn't it? using `=`.

Comment: Something like `for (int i = 0; i < SEQUENCEHISTORY; i++) Processed_Array[i] = History_host[i];`

Comment: @Afshin Yes this is one of the reasons why C++11 introduced `std::array`.

Comment: this `for` loop is wrong. UB - buffer overflow, since `SEQUENCEHISTORY > PROCESSINGSIZE` - I've updated answer.

Comment: hm...in his code he loops on PROCESSINGSIZE. I made a mistake.